# SalesForce to integrate with external RESTful service

Tags: rest, web-services, salesforce, restful-url, wadl

Being new to SalesForce Integration, I am trying to understand the capability of SalesForce to integrate with external RESTful service (WADL file) and execute to extract data to use in SalesForce UI functionality.

I understand that SalesForce is able to execute SOAP over HTTP (WSDL file) service to integrate but I see there is no solid documents online to explore whether SalesForce can also execute external WADL file.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in feature to consume a WADL.  You can however, just write your own Apex code to make restful callouts.

[Apex Restful Callouts Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)

[Invoking HTTP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_http.htm)

Comment: Thanks Matt Kaufman for your inputs.. Is there any online example use case for integrating with external RESTful service (WADL file) which I can refer and implement? Thanks.

Comment: Besides the links I already included. Try this: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/